# Uniqueness of continuous linear extensions to the second dual

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces (not necessarily Banach or reflexive) and $T:X\to Y$ is a continuous linear functional between them. Consider the functional $T'':X''\to Y''$, mapping from the second dual of $X$ into the second dual of $Y$, defined as $T''(x'')(y')\equiv x''(y'\circ T)$ for any $(y',x'')\in Y'\times X''$. Call this function $T''$ the *second adjoint* of $T$.

It can be shown that $T''$ is linear and continuous. In fact, the operator norm of $T''$ is the same as that of $T$.

What I want to show in addition is the following. Suppose that $W:X''\to Y''$ is another continuous linear functional between the second duals that agrees with $T''$ on $X$ (where $X$ is identified with its natural image in $X''$). That is, $W(x)(y')=T''(x)(y')=y'(T(x))$ for each $x\in X$ and $y'\in Y'$.

> Claim: $W=T''$ on $X''$. Put in another way, $X\subseteq\operatorname{ker}(W-T'')$ implies that $W-T''$ identically vanishes.

This would show that $T''$ is the unique continuous linear functional from $X''$ to $Y''$ that extends (in a sense) $T$.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If the completion of $X$ is not reflexive, then there are in general distinct (continuous linear) extensions of $T$ to $X''$. Is there perhaps a condition $\lVert W\rVert = \lVert T\rVert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer No further condition is given beyond $W$ being linear and $\|W\|<\infty$. I took the statement out of a textbook and was wondering, too, why it should be true, given that extensions $\textit{à la}$ Hahn–Banach are in general not unique. But I thought having the second duals involved would somehow make it a special case where uniqueness did hold.

Comment: It doesn't (in general). Consider a non-reflexive Banach space $X$, and let $Y = \mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$, whichever scalar field you prefer). Then you need nonzero continuous linear functionals on $X''$ that vanish on $X$, and Hahn-Banach tells you that they exist. It is different if $W$ is not only required to be continuous in the norm topologies but in the weak$^\ast$ topologies on $X''$ and $Y''$, then you have uniqueness since $X$ is weak$^\ast$-dense in $X''$. The norm-equality $\lVert W\rVert = \lVert T\rVert$ may also give uniqueness, but I don't know off-hand if it does.

Comment: @DanielFischer In the meanwhile, I've worked out the same counterexample. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension to the closure of $X$ in $X''$ is unique by continuity and the fact that $Y''$ is Hausdorff. That gives the uniqueness of the extension if the completion of $X$ is reflexive.

However, if the completion of $X$ is not reflexive and $Y \neq \{0\}$, then there are several distinct continuous linear extensions of $T$ to $X''$, since by the Hahn-Banach theorem there are then non-zero continuous linear functionals $\lambda$ on $X''$ with $X\subset \ker\lambda$, and $T'' + \lambda\otimes y''$ is then a continuous linear extension of $T$ for every $y''\in Y''$.

Comment: Does $\otimes$ denote tensor product?

Comment: I knew I forgot something. It means the function $x'' \mapsto \lambda(x'')\cdot y''$. It is an element of $X'''\otimes Y''$, but that's not really relevant.